# Couldn´t find pdf after adding \maketitle

Tags: errors, texstudio

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=2cm, rmargin=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\parindent=0cm
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsfonts,latexsym, cancel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcolumntype{E}{>{$}c>($)}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{40}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref} %Para poner hipervínculos

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{Title}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[L]{Mike Tyson}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}  % Da un error, mínimo headheight = 15

%% Título del artículo
\title{{\Huge\textbf{title}}}
\author{\textsc{Mike Tyson}
\thanks{Información relacionada con el autor}\\[0.2cm]
\normalsize Michigan University \\
\normalsize
\href {mailto:mike@mail}{mike@mail}
}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{titlesec} %Cambia formato de los números

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\maketitle

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

This is working all fine, except when I add the command `\maketitle`, as texstudio says
`Couldn´t find pdf, maybe it was eliminated`

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! Please, make your document example complete, compilable and if possible much shorter. Now are missed at least ˙\end{abstract}` and `end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MWE runs fine, both pdflatex and lualatex.

Try to run from a new fresh directory of your local machine.

[image: p]

Please correct your MWE adding `\end{document}` and commenting `\begin{abstract}`

This was intended as an answer. Just to show the image of `\maketitle` working.